# Reading private member of base class through inherited function (?)

Tags: c++, class, oop

In the following example the call `d.run();` prints `aD bD cD` and I don't understand why. I would think that it should print `aB bB cB aD bD cD` instead as we are pushing to the vector `vars_Base` of `Base` all 6 times (?)

Based on the output it seems to me that a copy is made of the `vars_Base` member to the `Derived` class although it is `private` to `Base` (?)

I should clarify that the point of this question is merely to understand the behavour of the example below - my intention is not to access the private members of `Base` through `Derived`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
private:
  std::vector<std::string> vars_Base;

protected:
  std::vector<std::string> &get_vars()
  {
    return vars_Base;
  }

public:
  void push_back(const std::string &str)
  {
    get_vars().push_back(str);
  }

  void run()
  {
    for (auto int_vars_it : get_vars())
    {
      std::cout << int_vars_it << " ";
    }
  }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Base b;
  b.push_back("aB");
  b.push_back("bB");
  b.push_back("cB");
  b.run(); // prints aB bB cB

  std::cout << std::endl;

  Derived d;
  d.push_back("aD");
  d.push_back("bD");
  d.push_back("cD");
  d.run(); // prints aD bD cD

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You push three things, so you print out three things. Unclear why you expect six. If you replaced `Derived d;` with `Base d;` would you still expect to print six items?

Comment: `b` is not a part of `d`. Even though the types inherit from each other, the variables are totally separate. So there is one `vars_Base` in `b` and another one in `d`.

Comment: @juanchopanza We are pushing to the vector `vars_Base` in all 6 cases, are we not (?)

Comment: @BillyJean Not to the same vector. This has nothing to do with inheritance, or private access. If you say `int i = 42;` do all ints become 42?

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables aren't shared between different instances of a class. While both `b` and `d` both have the members of `B`, they each have their own copy of the vector because the vector is an instance variable.

If you want all instances of a class to share the value of a variable, then you should make the variable static (you could also make the methods that use the vector static as well, if you want).

Comment: Ah, I see. Given that private members are not inherited, what variable is the object `d` pushing to?

Comment: @BillyJean Again, it has absolutely nothing with members being private (or public or protected.)

Comment: @juanchopanza But `d` is pushing values into a vector named `vars_Base`. This is private in `Base` and therefore not inherited to `Derived`. So where is this member-variable residing if it is not part of `d`?

Comment: @BillyJean `d` gets its own copy of everything in `Base`, including private variables. All private means is that subclasses can't directly access them. Each instance of a subclass still gets its own copies of everything in the base class, regardless of their access level.

Answer (score 2):

Each instance of any class of the hierarchy has its own  instance of `vars_Base`. So `B` has its own as well as `D`.

The fact that `vars_Base` is private in `Base` just imply that `vars_Base` is private in `Derived` too. Which means that you cannot access `b.vars_Base` or `d.vars_Base`.

But again, the two instances of `vars_Base` share nothing, so if you `push_back` stuff in `B` and in `D` those objects are stored in two different `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

`Base b` and `Derived D` are totally different objects and has no relationship with each other.

The class is a Blueprint of Objects and not the Object itself. Multiple Instances of the class is having different memory areas.

to get the output you want, you can write the code as

```
    Derived d;
    d.push_back("aB");
    d.push_back("bB");
    d.push_back("cB");

    d.push_back("aD");
    d.push_back("bD");
    d.push_back("cD");
    d.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its becouse `b` and `d` are different instances (objects). And both of them have their own variables. So it means there is one `std::vector` `vars_Base` in `b` and one in `d` and they **dont** share its content.

```
Object b

+---------------------------------+
|  b                              |
|                                 |
|  vars_Base        +----------+  |
|                   |    aB    |  |
|                   +----------+  |
|                   |    bB    |  |
|                   +----------+  |
|                   |    cB    |  | 
|                   +----------+  |
+---------------------------------+
```

Somewhere else in memory

```
Object d
+---------------------------------+
|  d                              |
|                                 |
|  vars_Base        +----------+  |
|                   |    aD    |  |
|                   +----------+  |
|                   |    bD    |  |
|                   +----------+  |
|                   |    cD    |  | 
|                   +----------+  |
+---------------------------------+
```

Instances of classes dont share its content, every of these object has its own memory and its own variables.